# How to Generate a Graph with Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, graph, statistics, visualization

The following is taken from the article A clinical appraisal of the pragmatic aspects of language (1987) by PRUTTING & KIRCHNER.

[image]

How can I use Microsoft Excel to Generate a similar graph? What is the way that I need to record data?

Comment: If you supply some data for us to have a go at, then that may help...

Comment: Seems like box and whiskers chart of excel but Solar Mike is right. You need to explain what kind of data you have and what you want to do with that chart.

Answer (score 0):

Created 4 series and just used X-Y scatter - formatting further ie gridlines etc
[image]